# Firebase storage image url not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, alamofire, firebase-storage

Hi I'm a newbie developer from Taiwan.
I have started to use firebase(ios) storage for my app and I want to use [ImageSliderShow](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow) to make a image slider view. After I got the image URL from firebase. I appended the url string into array then I ran the app. The image slider view works fine but the new image just showing nothing. Then I printed the url String before and after I appended into the array. It gave me two different string. Here is my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let URLString = loadURL()
    URLString.getURL(){
        (result:String) in
        self.ImageSliderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.ImageSliderView.slideshowInterval = 5.0
        self.ImageSliderView.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.insideScrollView
        self.ImageSliderView.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.ImageSliderView.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.ImageSliderView.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        self.ImageSliderView.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator()
        self.ImageSliderView.currentPageChanged = { page in
            print("current page:", page)
        }
        print("Result: \(result)")      ////print the result string before appended into array.
        self.kingfisherSource.append(KingfisherSource(urlString: String(result))!)
        print("alamoArray3: \(self.kingfisherSource[3].url)")   ////print the result string after appended into array.
        self.ImageSliderView.setImageInputs(self.kingfisherSource)
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ResultViewController.didTap))
        self.ImageSliderView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }
}
func didTap() {
    let fullScreenController = ImageSliderView.presentFullScreenController(from: self)
    // set the activity indicator for full screen controller (skipping the line will show no activity indicator)
    fullScreenController.slideshow.activityIndicator = DefaultActivityIndicator(style: .white, color: nil)
}
```

getURL function:

```
class loadURL {
let storage = Storage.storage(url: "my-firebase-storage-bucket")
func getURL(completion:@escaping (_ result:String)->Void) {
    self.storage.reference().child("images/breakfast/1/1.jpg").downloadURL { url, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Firebase Image URL error: \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            print("Firebase Image URL: \(String(describing: url!))")
            completion("\(String(describing: url))")
        }
    }   
}
```

The output:

```
Firebase Image URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-firebase-storage-bucket/o/images%2Fbreakfast%2F1%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=15ee8094-ac50-4e93-adc0-200793181bfc
Result: Optional(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-firebase-storage-bucket/o/images%2Fbreakfast%2F1%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=15ee8094-ac50-4e93-adc0-200793181bfc)
alamoArray3: Optional(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-firebase-storage-bucket/o/images%2Fbreakfast%2F1%2F1.jpg?alt=m ... 3181bfc)
```

The 3rd output just weird... Is it possible be an encoding issue?
And I apology about my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just figure it out. I let the type of result as URL and then it just works perfectly.